Constructing a Discontinuous Extension from Continuous Functions on Overlapping Domains
I am dealing with the following problem:

Let $(X, \tau),(Y, \tau^\prime)$ be topological spaces, $\emptyset \neq A, B \subset X$ with $A \cap B \neq \emptyset, f: A \rightarrow Y$ and $g: B \rightarrow Y$ functions such that $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x \in A \cap B$, where $f$ is continuous on A and $g$ is continuous on
$B$. Define $h: A \cup B \rightarrow Y$ by $h(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}f(x) & \text { if } x \in A \\ g(x) & \text { if } x \in B\end{array}\right.$.
Give an example - if any- where $h$ is not continuous on $A \cup B$.

My attempts using Euclidean spaces with the usual metric did not help. Then I considered point sets of the form: $X = \{a,b,c\}$, $A = \{a,b \}$, $ B= \{b,c \}$ with (for instance) $\tau = \{\emptyset, X, \{a\} \}$, and $Y = \{0,1 \}$ with $\tau^\prime = \{ \emptyset, Y, \{1\}\}$. But in such settings no matter how I change the functions, either one of $f,g$ is not continuous or $h$ is continuous. I believe there is a relatively basic example but I could not manage to find it. (I also tried to prove that  such an example cannot exist but it did not help either, so I think that there is indeed such an example.)
Note: My convention is that whenever there is a function on a subset of $X$, I use the subspace topology (and hence relative openness) in the definition of continuity.

Let $A=(1,2)\cup(-2,0)$ and $B=[0,2)$. We consider the function $f:t\mapsto\mathbf{1}_{[0,\infty)}(t)$. Its restrictions to $A$ and $B$ are continuous, however its restriction to $A\cup B=(-2,2)$ is not.

Let $S = \{z \in \mathbb C: |z| = 1\}$ be the circle, and let $\phi:S \rightarrow \mathbb [0, 2\pi)$ denote the (unique) function satisfying $z = \exp(i\phi(z))$ for all $z \in S$. This function is continuous everywhere on $S$ except the point $z = 1$. Let $A = S \setminus \{1\}$ and $B = \{z \in S: \mathrm{Im} z \ge 0\}$. Let $f:A \rightarrow [0, 2\pi)$ and $g:B \rightarrow [0, 2\pi)$ denote the corresponding restrictions of $\phi$. It is easy to check that $f$ and $g$ are continuous, but their union $h$ (which coincides with $\phi$) is not.
